# Kotlin compile error using self generic type bound

Tags: kotlin, generics, types, state-machine

Suppose I have the following code to simulate a state machine in Kotlin:

```
sealed interface State {
    object A : State
    object B: State
    object C: State
    object D: State
}

interface StateMachine<Self: StateMachine<Self, *>, T: State>

fun <S : StateMachine<S, State.A>> S.transitionX() = object : StateMachine<S, State.B> {}

fun <S: StateMachine<S, State.B>> S.transitionQ() = object : StateMachine<S, State.B> {}

object Start: StateMachine<Start, State.A>

fun main() {
    val stateMachine = Start.transitionX().transitionQ()
}
```

However, this doesn't compile because

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public fun <S : StateMachine<TypeVariable(S), State.B>> TypeVariable(S).transitionQ(): StateMachine<TypeVariable(S), State.B> defined in root package in file Main.kt
```

which is probably because of the `Self` generic constraint.

Ideally, `stateMachine` should have a type `StateMachine<StateMachine<Start, State.A>, State.B`.

I was wondering if there's any way to fix the generic constraints so that this does compile? Note: I am aware that the `Self` generic parameter isn't actually needed for this state machine, but I'm just interested to see if this is actually possible.

I have tried a few different changes to the generic type bounds, but the closest I could get resulted in `stateMachine` just having a type of `StateMachine<Start, State.B>`, which isn't quite what I want. Other changes I've made have just caused the Kotlin Finite Bound Restriction error.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to do with the self type, so it's hard to say whether these solutions will actually work for your use case.

1. You don't need to involve new generics in your function itself, only within its receiver and return type. So you can use `*` types to represent `Self`. This of course assumes that the Self type isn't needed outside its own private implementation, like if you had a `fun copy(): Self`. It's impossible to define an implementation of your interface using an anonymous object, since it has to have a class name to be able to describe its own self type. So you either need to define it with a named object outside the function, or by defining a class inside the function and returning an instance of it.

```
fun StateMachine<*, State.A>.transitionX(): StateMachine<*, State.B> {
    class Impl: StateMachine<Impl, State.B>{
        
    }
    return Impl()
}
```

2. You could define explicit interfaces for all the possible children and use those. Since State is sealed, this is possible.

```
interface AStateMachine: StateMachine<AStateMachine, State.A>
interface BStateMachine: StateMachine<BStateMachine, State.B>
interface CStateMachine: StateMachine<CStateMachine, State.C>
interface DStateMachine: StateMachine<DStateMachine, State.D>

fun AStateMachine.transitionX() = object : BStateMachine {}

fun BStateMachine.transitionQ() = object : CStateMachine {}
```